# Calling an external command in Swift

Tags: exec, swift

How can I call an external command (launch a subprocess) from a Swift script?

Perhaps something like `call(["ls", "-l"])` in Python.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can still use NSTask in Swift. Your example would be something like this.

```
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/bin/ls"
task.arguments = ["-l"]
task.launch()
```

**Swift 3+, macOS 10.13+**

```
let task = Process()
task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/ls")
task.arguments = ["-l"]
task.run()
```

Comment: Ah yeah. duh.. Still wrapping my head around this thing :)

Comment: This is outdated: use `Process` with Swift 3.